# Wcf service not running

Tags: c#, wcf

While i am adding a new wcf service to my existing application by choosing (Solution Explorer->Add new folder->gave name ,then on that folder i choose add new item->wcf service ->name->ok)
result: a interface and a implementation class. after doing some logic while i'm trying to run the wcf service its getting error .

Changed (Added)my web.config as below:
 Collapse | Copy Code

      
        
        
       (for 1st service)

```
   <service name="Intranet.WCF_Service.CGI_Automated" behaviorConfiguration="Intranet.WCF_Service.CGI_AutomatedBehavior">
    <endpoint address="../WCF Service/CGI_Automated.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Intranet.WCF_Service.ICGI_Automated" behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour" />
    <endpoint name="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service> (for 2nd one)

</services>
```

Collapse | Copy Code

```
     <behavior name="Intranet.WCF_Service.CGI_AutomatedBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>

    <behavior name="Serviceforcgi.Service1Behavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

please suggest me on this ,i am confused here .

Comment: It could be useful to give details about the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you followed the [app.config file structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731734%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). There is no need to give same behaviour in different name. Check the endpoint address, it should not contains space.

Use [WCF Configuration Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732009%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (available in Tools) for simple service/endpoint/behaviour/etc.